# Design multiple views in RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button

There is a `RadioGroup` which contains three `RadioButtons`.
Now I am using `\n` to realize two lines(The image shows).

[image: Here is what I have done.]

Then I want the first line have smaller text than bellow.How can I achieve this?

Comment: why dont you use custom layout rather than using radio group if you have fixed number of buttons?

Comment: `RadioGroup`  is easier to control only one is selected. Or is custom layout the only way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use a RadioButton as a Background view for the TextViews

Comment: you can use custom layout if you have only static fields like in the picture its 3 and you can manage their background their click events

Comment: @xiaoyuan Use Spannable String to achieve this. `text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), text.length() - "stackOverflow".length(), text.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);` [read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Comment: @RethinavelPillai Thanks a lot. I will try it.